# Regex in file names

Tags: regex

I use free little program Metamorphose for changing file names.
Problem is I need to use regex to change names in order as shown below:

```
Find: nice-tree-([\s\S]*?)
Replace: nice-tree-$1-abc
```

As you can see all files that start with nice-tree-ANYTHING should be replaced with -abc at the end of every file name.
I'm everything just not expert for regex usage...

Both of you were right. It works now. Thanks.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: (.*) would match `ANYTHING` so that any `SOMETHING` would get matched at that point, or did I understand you wrong?

Comment: do you consider file extensions in the file name?

Comment: Get rid of the `?` after the `*`. You don't want minimal matching here. And just use `.` instead of `\s\S` (or `\d\D`, `\w\W`, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to replace the full file name with the extension. The following regex would match all the file names that you are looking for.

/nice-tree-.+/